# How do I set only a single element in a tensor in theano?

Tags: python, theano

Currently I have this code which sets the first element of my tensor output.

```
        a = T.set_subtensor(output[0][0], rotation[0][0])
        output = T.set_subtensor(output[0],a)

        # outputs as expected:
        # [
        #   [.934, 0],
        #   [0,    0]
        # ]
```

Unfortunate doing:

```
       output = T.set_subtensor(output[0][0], rotation[0][0])
       # outputs single array [.934, 0]... this is not what I want
```

Only outputs the first row which is not what I want. Is it possible to create a statement that combines the first 2 lines to give me the matrix that I want?

Answer (score 3):

You most probably want to replace

```
output = T.set_subtensor(output[0][0], rotation[0][0])
```

with

```
output = T.set_subtensor(output[0, 0], rotation[0, 0])
```

if possible.